# Why is == operator for string comparison linear time (seemingly) with respect to either strings length?

Tags: c++, string, equals, operator-keyword, equality

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
using namespace std::chrono;
int main(int arc, char* argv[]) {
    const std::string password = "a";
    int correct = 1;
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    if(password != argv[1])
        correct = 0;
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = duration_cast<nanoseconds> (end-start).count();
    std::cout << "time: " << elapsed << "\n";
    return correct;
}
```

It takes on average >50% longer to compare "a" == "b" and "a" == "bbbbbbbbbbbbb..."(length ~250).

Why is this the case? Shouldn't the string compare function break immediately after seeing that the first characters are not equal (or that the length of the strings aren't equal)?

A number of references also mention that string comparison is linear complexity in the length of both input strings (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp). I don't understand why this would be the case.. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The string `== operator` relies on the `compare()` method.
Looking at the implementation available on my TDMGCC, I found this:

```
// This is the overloaded one called when you compare to argv[1]
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
    int
    basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::
    compare(const _CharT* __s) const
    {
      __glibcxx_requires_string(__s);
      const size_type __size = this->size();
      const size_type __osize = traits_type::length(__s);
      const size_type __len = std::min(__size, __osize);
      int __r = traits_type::compare(_M_data(), __s, __len);
      if (!__r)
    __r = _S_compare(__size, __osize);
      return __r;
    }
```

As you can see, before comparing the lengths it first calls this `traits_type::compare()`, which is basically the `memcmp()`:

```
      static int
      compare(const char_type* __s1, const char_type* __s2, size_t __n)
      { return __builtin_memcmp(__s1, __s2, __n); }
```

Therefore, if I am not wrong, the comparison will be linear time as you mentioned.

Comment: Implementation dependent. MSVC for example checks the lengths before calling `compare` (which makes more sense)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note here is that `operator==()` internally uses `compare()` method, as mentioned [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/).

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147797/3844480) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4145897/3844480), many implementations of the `compare()` method rely on `memcmp`. (or some equivalent function) You can see in [this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/memcmp.c) C implementation that the algorithm used by `memcmp` has linear time complexity. That particular implementation is given below.

```
int
memcmp (const PTR str1, const PTR str2, size_t count)
{
  register const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char*)str1;
  register const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char*)str2;

  while (count-- > 0)
  {
    if (*s1++ != *s2++)
      return s1[-1] < s2[-1] ? -1 : 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Due to this internal implementation of the `compare()` method, and the optimizations involved, you will probably need larger sizes of strings to be able to observe the linear trend in the time it takes for the method to execute.

Comment: Do you know what count is here? Is it the byte length of the longer string?
Can you give some insight into the logic of that ternary operator? I'm having trouble understanding what's going on here. We're comparing blocks of memory and if they're not equal, checking the previous block (?)

Comment: Actually, in that particular implementation, `count` refers to the number of characters to be compared. The ternary operator is used when two different characters of `s1` and `s2` are found. (see the `if` condition above) It helps decide which value to return from `memcmp`. If `s1` is lexically 'smaller', it returns -1, and if it is lexically 'larger', it returns 1.